# NullpointerException onPictureTaken

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

I got some problems with taking pictures via android camera.

The main purpose is by using `CameraControlView` preview the camera and take picture via a button.

```
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/sample_picture.jpg";
    Bitmap photo;
    mOpenCvCameraView.takePicture(fileName);
    //viewNavi.setDisplayedChild(viewNavi.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.image_view)));
    viewNavi.showNext();
    Bitmap newp =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);
    if(newp==null)
        return;

    ImageView imgViewResult = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewResult);
    imgViewResult.setImageBitmap(newp);
```

`CameraControlView.takePicture(fileLocation);`
I want to use the saved picture on an imageView after that point but I could not, because saving the picture progress is not done yet (which is run by `OnPictureTaken`). So I wanted to be sure if the taking picture process is done.
Then I found a useful explaination on the internet which is the `OnPictureTaken` progress is the responsible method for saving pictures:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving a bitmap to file");
        // The camera preview was automatically stopped. Start it again.
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
        // Write the image in a file (in jpeg format)

        /*My code
        ImageView imgResult = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewResult);
        Bitmap newp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        imgResult.setImageBitmap(newp);
        */

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mPictureFileName);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();

        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
        }
        isPictureTaken = true; 
    }
```

The real problem is when I tried to add this code segment:

```
    ImageView imgResult = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewResult);
    Bitmap newp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    imgResult.setImageBitmap(newp);
```

In to the `onPictureTaken` as shown above. I got a `NullPointerException`.

Is there a way that only take taken picture into a bitmap, and in sync way (means the way I have been using is not suitable for my project. When I want to setImageBitmap after takePicture. The code sends me previous taken pic[because I am using the same save location and overwrite the pic] or null)

Any explanation would be great.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: try to use intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE for taken the picture from camera, Because it open the defualt camera of the Android device and saved at the sd card.

Comment: Thanks sunil. I am aware of intent actionview. However if I use intent actionview I need to take care of the saved pictures into the gallery (After some point memory is going to fulfill with the unwanted pictures). Also I don't want to users should not be able to change any setting on the picture taking screen. Because camera interface is various on different android devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a complete different way. I simply just took last frame of the camera_preview. Thus I don't have to handle the previous problems which I explained above.

```
 public class CameraControlActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2, OnTouchListener


 public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mGray = new Mat();
    mRgba = new Mat();
 }

public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mGray.release();
    mRgba.release();
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    return mRgba;
}
```

And finally in the button click event

```
    Bitmap img = Bitmap.createBitmap(640, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, img);
    img = drawORBFeatures(img);
    imgViewResult.setImageBitmap(img);
    viewNavi.setDisplayedChild(viewNavi.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.image_view)));
```

I hope someone will find this article useful. Because when it comes to taking picture on android, I could not find simpler method than this on the internet. And there are a lot of dicussion how to handle the side effects of other methods (taking photo without saving it or exceptions on onPictureTaken method, etc.)